# AVPlayer Dynamic Volume control

Tags: objective-c, ios, media-player, avfoundation, avplayer

How can I change the volume of the AVPlayer Dynamically? I mean, I want to mute the volume every time a button is pressed. the given code seems to change it in compile time only. How to do it during runtime???

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; 
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self.mPlayer = player;
[mPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `playerItem` new instances of AVMutableAudioMix during playback to change levels dynamically. Just link your button to an action method that creates a new AVMutableAudioMix instance (like you have done above) with the appropriate values, and use playerItem's `setAudioMix:` method to set the new mix values. (If you're working across methods, don't forget to save a reference to your playerItem instance to access it later.)

(N.B. `setAudioMix:` isn't mentioned explicitly in the [AVPlayerItem docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) because it is a synthesized setter for the `audioMix` property.)