# Get Volume of AVPlayer in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, avplayer

There are plenty of questions asking how to **set** the volume of an `AVPlayer`, but *how do you get the current volume of the player in iOS*?

For example, I am trying to fade a song out from its current level. I could save the volume elsewhere and refer to it, but would rather read the value directly from the AVPlayer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AVPlayer` is contains one or more `AVPlayerItem` objects, and it is through these objects that you can get and set audio levels for media played by an AVPlayer. Head to the [AVPlayerItem docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and look at the `audioMix` property, and also check out my answer to a [slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206991/avplayer-dynamic-volume-control/10218004#10218004) that should still provide some info.

---

Following up after your comment, this is (I think) how you would get the volume values from the `- (BOOL)getVolumeRampForTime:(CMTime)time startVolume:(float *)startVolume endVolume:(float *)endVolume timeRange:(CMTimeRange *)timeRange` method:

```
// Get your AVAudioMixInputParameters instance, here called audioMixInputParameters
// currentTime is the current playhead time of your media

float startVolume;
float endVolume;
CMTimeRange timeRange;

bool success = [audioMixInputParameters getVolumeRampForTime: currentTime
                                                 startVolume: &startVolume
                                                   endVolume: &endVolume
                                                   timeRange: &timeRange];

// startVolume and endVolume should now be set
NSLog(@"Start volume: %f | End volume: %f", startVolume, endVolume);
```

Comment: So there's `- (void) getVolumeRampForTime:startVolume:endVolume:timeRange:` on `AVAudioMixInputParameters` which comes from `player.audioMix.inputParameters[]`. Still not sure how to pull volume for the current time, but I'll post it when I figure it out.

Comment: The `startVolume:` and `endVolume:` parameters of that method ask for pointers to floats, so that is the mechanism for extracting the volume values.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's [`AVPlayer` documentation for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it lists a volume property, but the documentation for the [same class in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't show one listed. Would your project allow you to use `AVAudioPlayer` instead? That one *does* have a synthesized volume property for iOS that's much more easily set/retrieved.

Comment: Thanks Shaun but I am using the AVPlayer to stream a remote mp3 - which does not appear to be possible with the `AVAudioPlayer`

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You could use the volume property of the AVPlayer class.  Here's the [AVPlayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) link.  Quoting from it:</strike>

> volume
>   Indicates the current audio volume of the player.
>
> @property(nonatomic) float volume
>   Discussion
>   0.0 means “silence all audio,” 1.0 means “play at the full volume of the current item.”
>
> Availability
>   Available in OS X v10.7 and later.
>
> Declared In
>   AVPlayer.h

edit:

You could try geting the system volume instead. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255006/get-system-volume-ios) provides 2 ways.

Comment: That property is only available on OS X. iOS does not have it.